# Why does this simple callback execute before the setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, callback

This snippet logs 'output 2' ahead of 'output 1', which is cool due to the `setTimeout`.

```js
const func1 = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('output 1');
  }, 3000);
};

const func2 = () => {
  console.log('output 2');
};

func1();
func2();
```

In this snippet, I used a callback, but it gave me the same result as the last snippet, why doesn't `func1` execute before `func2`? How can I make `func2` execute after `func1`?

```js
const func1 = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('output 1');
  }, 3000);
};

const func2 = () => {
  console.log('output 2');
};

const main = (a, b) => {
  a();
  b();
};

main(func1, func2);
```

Comment: Why should it? Your `main()` just adds a layer around your first snippet. It doesn't change anything of the flow of your script.

Comment: `setTimeout` registers for async - passing functions around does nothing like that by default.

Answer (score 2):

> why doesn't func1 execute before func2

It does.

1. Func1 sets a timeout running
2. Func2 logs
3. 3 seconds later the callback function you pass to `setTimeout` is called

If you want to make Func2 run after step 3, then you need to call it *at the end of the callback you pass to `setTimeout`*.

Comment: Can you please show me a code which makes func2 run after step3?

Answer (score 0):

**Simple explanation -**

Function 2 wouldn't wait for the completion of the timer started in function 1.

```
func1();
func2();
```

When you execute both functions, function 1 sets the timer and function 2 logs out.

Eventually, function 1 logs out after 3 seconds.

Your second snippet does pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not wait for setTimeout to finish and then execute next functions.
whenvever javascript encounters a setTimeOut it store functions with provided timeout, in this case 3 seconds. after storing it in call stack it just starts to execute functions below it and since there is nothing in second function it get executed right away ( before 3 seconds obviously ). that's why you are seeing the log of second function before the log of first function.
To execute first function and then execute second function you can use promise chaining.
Example:

```
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('output 1');
        resolve();
     }, 3000);
 }).then(function(result) {
     console.log('output 2');
 });
```

Hope it will help. Feel free to correct if i am wrong.